# Find minimum non repeating sequence using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

Consider a sequence consisting of letters `a,g,c,t`. You have to find the minimum non-repeating sequence of characters and their length.Also note the non-repeating character should be in sequence.

For example in the sequence `'aaggcct'` the answer is minimum non-repeating character is `t` where `t` is the least non-repeating set of character and length is `1`.Even though `aa,gg,cc,ag,gc,ct` is non repeating since `t` is least non repeating with length `1` the answer is `t.`
When I say `t` is non-repeating then there is no other `t` in the sequence.

For the sequence `'aaggcctt'` one of the answer is `aa,` for example, is the least non-repeating set of characters.Even though `aag` is non-repeating the least non-repeating length is 2 hence it is not considered.
When I say `'aa'` is non-repeating there is no other `aa` in the sequence.
The complete answer is below

```
    DATA    LENGTH
    ag       2
    gg       2
    ct       2
    cc       2
    aa       2
    tt       2
    gc       2
```

One more example for the sequence `'aaagggcccttt'` here `aa` is repeated hence not in the answer. When I say `'aa'` is repeated because in `'aaa'` there are two `'aa'` staring from position 1 `aa` and then position 2 `aa`

```
    DATA    LENGTH
    ag       2
    ct       2
    gc       2
```

Comment: Sample data and a description of the technical issue you are having would help a lot.

Comment: Is this supposed to be code golf, or something you actually need to do? Either way it isn't very clear; particularly the last part where the 'answer' doesn't seem related to the sequence, and contains repeated characters.

Comment: it is an interview question ,i have edited the same for clarity

Comment: i have added one more example

Comment: In your second example you say the answer is `aa`. How is that "non-repeating"? And why isn't `a` the correct answer? That is non-repeating (obviously since it is just one letter, nothing to repeat there). Do you understand now why everybody is confused? Unless you can give a clear problem statement, your question will remain closed.

Comment: i have given clarity as much as possible

Comment: Would the minimum non-repeating string for `agaga` be `gag`, since `a`, `g`, `ag`, `ga` and `aga` all repeat?

Comment: yes gag would be the minimum non-repeating string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find all the substrings of a string, then count them to see how many of them repeat and exclude any that not unique and then find the set of substrings that have the minimum length for each string:

So, if you have the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, value ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'agaga' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'aaggcct' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'aaggcctt' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'aaagggcccttt' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use:

```sql
WITH substrings ( id, value, length, pos ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         LENGTH( value ),
         1
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         value,
         CASE pos
         WHEN 1
         THEN length - 1
         ELSE length
         END,
         CASE pos
         WHEN 1
         THEN LENGTH(value) - (length-2)
         ELSE pos-1
         END
  FROM   substrings
  WHERE  length > 1
  OR     pos > 1
),
non_repeats ( id, value, substring ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         MIN( value ),
         SUBSTR( value, pos, length )
  FROM   substrings s
  GROUP BY id, SUBSTR( value, pos, length )
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
SELECT id,
       value,
       substring
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         value,
         substring,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY LENGTH( substring ) ASC ) AS rnk
  FROM   non_repeats
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID | VALUE        | SUBSTRING
> -: | :----------- | :--------
>  1 | agaga        | gag      
>  2 | aaggcct      | t        
>  3 | aaggcctt     | gc       
>  3 | aaggcctt     | cc       
>  3 | aaggcctt     | ct       
>  3 | aaggcctt     | ag       
>  3 | aaggcctt     | aa       
>  3 | aaggcctt     | tt       
>  3 | aaggcctt     | gg       
>  4 | aaagggcccttt | ct       
>  4 | aaagggcccttt | gc       
>  4 | aaagggcccttt | ag
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f27e57702b114eb2e39b5b92c7bb9c69)*

Comment: hi @MT0, since we are using recursive for substrings, will there be impact in performance if the input size increases to say 150+ characters

Comment: @psaraj12 Of course there will. If you have a 150 character string then you will have 150 1-character strings, 149 2-character strings, 148 3-character strings .... 2, 149-character strings and 1 150-character string so generalising for an `n`-character string then you will have `n(n+1)/2` substrings so the number of rows generated is proportional to the square of the length. You can reduce the search space by checking substrings from the shortest to the longest but you still might need to generate the all the rows if the string was `aaaaaaa` (for example).

Comment: thanks for the explanation ,also wanted to know is there any restriction in the use of the recursive query 'substrings' like say it can loop only these many number of times

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an answer where first I find all combinations of substring which are not repeated using two iterators and then find the least length non-repeating substring.

```
        WITH dna
         AS (SELECT value
                    ||'$' AS seq,
                    id
             FROM   test_data),
         iterator
         AS (SELECT column_value n,
                    id
             FROM   dna
                    cross join TABLE(Cast(MULTISET (SELECT LEVEL
                                              FROM   dual
                                              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Length(seq)) AS
                                           sys.ODCINUMBERLIST))),
         target_data
         AS (SELECT Count(1)                             cnt,
                    Substr(dna2.seq, i1.n, i2.n)         data1,
                    Length(Substr(dna2.seq, i1.n, i2.n)) lngth,
                    dna2.id,
                    Replace(seq, '$', '')                value
             FROM   dna dna2,
                    iterator i1,
                    iterator i2
             WHERE  dna2.id = i1.id
                    AND dna2.id = i2.id
             GROUP  BY Substr(dna2.seq, i1.n, i2.n),
                       Length(Substr(dna2.seq, i1.n, i2.n)),
                       dna2.id,
                       seq
             HAVING Count(1) = 1)
    SELECT id,
           value,
           data1
    FROM   target_data td
    WHERE  lngth = (SELECT Min(lngth)
                    FROM   target_data td1
                    WHERE  td1.id = td.id)
    ORDER  BY id;
```

The output is

```
    ID  VALUE          DATA1
    1   agaga           gag
    2   aaggcct         t
    3   aaggcctt        cc
    3   aaggcctt        gc
    3   aaggcctt        ag
    3   aaggcctt        ct
    3   aaggcctt        gg
    3   aaggcctt        aa
    3   aaggcctt        tt
    4   aaagggcccttt    ct
    4   aaagggcccttt    ag
    4   aaagggcccttt    gc
```